# Windows 10 updates grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gparted, grubrescue

I have a grub rescue issue. On boot Windows 10 decided to update and after that the grub menu got corrupted. Now I am stuck at the grub rescue mode. My attempts to locate the grub2 on the partitions did not lead to anything.

When I try to boot through the Boot-Repair drive, the system does not boot into it and straightaway boots into the grub rescue screen.

Grub rescue screen:

[image]

GParted of my `/dev/sda` drive:

[image]

The interesting thing is the now I cannot boot through the *Try Ubuntu* or *Install Ubuntu* options, so I had to resort just to the GParted ISO.

Comment: By seeing title of the question it seems you are asking question related to Windows not Ubuntu. So please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) before asking question or if you have Ubuntu installed please specify the version of Ubuntu and is it installed properly?

Comment: As I can see, you have a dual boot PC with Windows 10 and Fedora on it. Nothing strictly related to Ubuntu. That makes your question off-topic here. Try, instead, our sister-site SuperUser here: http://superuser.com/

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my system. I differ to say that this question is valid.

Comment: Valid question. **Windows 10 Anniversary Update** wiped his Ubuntu partition to **unallocated** space. This will possiblly impact a large number of Ubuntu users who wonder why they can no longer boot Ubuntu. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

You may have been bitten by the notorious `Windows 10 Anniversary Update`. It's known to possibly do two things... overwrite GRUB with a Windows Boot Manager, and/or delete the Ubuntu/Linux partition.

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD and start gparted. Make a screenshot of your sda drive and post it here for me to review.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Yes I am very sure it was the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. I have added the GPart of my SDA drive. (http://imgur.com/a/S6Txk) Interestingly now I cannot boot through the Ubuntu Live DVD into the Try Without Install (image 2 of the link) or Install Option. I only get a partially visible terminal with list of commands.

Comment: Yes, it turned your Ubuntu partition into unallocated space! Download the `MiniTool Partition Wizard Free Edition` at **https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html** in Windows, and try to run it and see if it'll turn your unallocated back into an EXT4 partition. Report back. Cheers, Al

Comment: I have tired with Mini Tool Partition Wizard but once I boot into the system, my laptop screen does not light up. Hence I am unable to see which dad to mark as EXT4. Are there any command line options.

Comment: Did you download .exe file, or the .iso image? Do your brightness fkeys help at all? Try the .iso image and burn it to a CD/DVD. If you already tried the .iso file, and you can get to Windows, download the .exe and try again. If you already did that, you might just have to reinstall Ubuntu. Keep us posted. Cheers, Al